# Getting text from a file, BufferedReader, output looks ok but doesn't equal "true" or "false" (what's in the file)

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

I'm trying to get info from a file (it's to be used as a settings file, true or false values), using the following code:

```
File information = new File(aPath + "/plugins/ArenaCraft/info.acs");

ArrayList<String> info = new ArrayList<String>();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(information));
String line;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     String[] sLine = line.split(":");
     if(sLine[1] == "true"){
         info.add("true");
     }
     if(sLine[1] == "false"){
         info.add("false");
     }
     if(sLine[1] == null){
         System.err.println("[ArenaCraft]  sLine[1] is NULL.");
     }
     if(sLine[1] != "true" && sLine[1] != "false" && sLine[1] != null){
         System.err.println("[ArenaCraft]  sLine[1] is not NULL, but it's not \"true\" or \"false\".");
         System.err.println("[ArenaCraft]  sLine[1] is: " + sLine[1]);
     }
}

br.close();
return info;
```

This, however, is outputting the

```
[ArenaCraft]  sLine[1] is not NULL, but it's not "true" or "false".
```

message. It then outputs, exactly,

```
[ArenaCraft]  sLine[1] is: true
```

So, I don't understand why it says it's not null or true or false.
Do you guys imagine why that would happen?

The contents of the file I'm trying to read, with no encoding, follow:

```
notices:true
```

and nothing more.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't compare String values using `==`. Use `equals()`

Comment: Congratulations! You are the winner of the "Who posts the == vs. equals question on Dec 22th" contest.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't know what was causing the problem so I didn't check for exactly comparing strings. I'm sort of new to java, wasn't sure where the problem could lay in.

Comment: @HolyThunder Don't worry. It's just a bit sarcasm because problems rooted in the same problem as your question come up every single day at least once. So one could say it's a weakness of Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `a==b` instead of `a.equals(b)` See: [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus).

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much! I've been messing around with it for about 2 hours trying to see what was happening!

Answer (score 1):

Well, the == operator compares references. You want to use the equals() method here:

```
if (sLine[1].equals("true")) {
    [...]
}
```

Also, you should use the [String.trim()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) method, to ensure that there are no leading or trailing spaces in your strings. A line like this: `param = true` would parse to " true" with your code, which is not equal to "true".

```
if (sLine[1].trim().equals("true")) {
    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, change:

```
if (cond1) { ... }
if (cond2) { ... }  
if (cond3) { ... }
if (!cond1 && !cond2 && !cond3) { .... }
```

to

```
if (cond1) { ... }
else if (cond2) { ... }
else if (cond3) { ... }
else { ... }
```

in cases when at most one of the conditions can be true, like in your example.

Comment: Thanks! I'm rather new to java, I know some and can work my way around most basic stuff but I don't know these kind of guidelines!

Answer (score 0):

Use `equals()` method for String content comparison , `==` for String reference comparison